# Angular: Watch collection on field change and make a calculations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

I'm building a simple page with Angular and I got some problems with watchers that I need to create there. First of all my collection looks something like this:

```
$scope.products = [
  {
    "name": "Milk",
    "price": 2,
    "currency": "USD",
    "exchangeRate": 1.5,
    "localCurrencyPrice": 0
  },
  {
    "name": "Bread",
    "price": 1,
    "currency": "EUR",
    "exchangeRate": 1,
    "localCurrencyPrice": 0
  },
  {
    "name": "Skittles",
    "price": 3,
    "currency": "GBP",
    "exchangeRate": 2,
    "localCurrencyPrice": 0
  },
  {
    "name": "Nesquik",
    "price": 10,
    "currency": "CHF",
    "exchangeRate": 2.5,
    "localCurrencyPrice": 0
  }
]
```

I will be showing a field for each and every property of the object in the collection, so it's going to look something like this: https://plnkr.co/edit/hnuC1IAMZAQznDYP6tsQ?p=preview

As you can see I can add or remove items, so the array length is not a constant number on start up. I want to create watchers for every "**PRICE**" and "**EXCHANGERATE**" field in each item and when user changes the value of one of them, they both should be mulplied and the result should be filled up into the "**LOCALCURRENCYPRICE**" field. /e.g. in the first item "*Milk*" when I change the *price* to 1.7, it should be muplied with the *exchangeRate* of 1.5 and the result should be populated into the *localCurrencyPrice* model and field/. When you add a new item into the products array, watchers for it's "**price**" and "**exchangeRate**" properties should be added as well.

Any ideas how this can be done?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a ng-change function with your template ( https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange )

For initialization; you can use ng-init ( https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

Call it with :

```
 <div class="field" ng-repeat="(fieldKey, fieldValue) in item">
    <div ng-init="calcFunc(item)">{{ fieldKey.toUpperCase() }}:
    <input type="text" name="item.name" ng-model="fieldValue" ng-change="myFunc(fieldKey, fieldValue,item)/> </div>
  </div>
```

Add it to your controller with your logic :

```
$scope.calcFunc = function(item) {
    item['LOCALCURRENCYPRICE'] = item['EXCHANGERATE'] * item['PRICE'];
}

$scope.myFunc = function(key,val,item){
       if(key === 'EXCHANGERATE') .... // check if the updated field is one of your's requested
      {
         //edit item['LOCALCURRENCYPRICE'] 
         $scope.calcFunc(item);

      }

}
```

Comment: I was thinking of using the `ng-change`, but then I thought I would have problems on actual initialization of the list, because it's not going to be fired. And when for some reason I change the whole item object it also won't be executed. Am I wrong that `ng-change` is fired only when user iteracts with the input?

Comment: you can have a ng-init for initialization. I update my code for that.

Comment: `ng-init` is a good solution, thanks. Will try it and see if it works as expected :)

Answer (score 0):

i tried it in another way and its in the way you like it:

**what i did**:
 **1.**Added ng-model to price,exchangerate,localcurrencyrate.
 **2.**Next in the ng-model of localcurrencyrate i multiplied price and  exchangerate.thats it

just copy paste below code and test it you will get exactly wat you needed:)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in products">
        <td>
          <!-- field name -->
          <br>
          <!-- fields -->
          <b>Item &nbsp;{{$index}}</b>
          <button ng-click="RemoveItem()">Remove Item</button><br><br>
          NAME:<input type="text" value="{{x.name}}" /><br>
          PRICE:<input type="text"  value="{{x.price}}" ng-model="x.price"/><br>
          CURRENCY:<input type="text"  value="{{x.currency}}"/><br>
          EXCHANGERATE:<input type="text" value="{{x.exchangeRate}}" ng-model="x.exchangeRate"/><br>
          LOCALCURRENCYPRICE:<input type="text" value="{{x.localCurrencyPrice}}" ng-model="x.price*x.exchangeRate"/><br>
          <br>

       </td>

      </tr>
    </table>
     <button ng-click="AddNewItem()">Add New Item</button>

    <br>

    </div>

    <script>

    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope) 
    {
    $scope.AddNewItem = function() {
          $scope.products.push( {
            name: "",
            price: 0,
            currency: "",
            exchangeRate: 0,
            localCurrencyPrice: 0
          } );
        };

        $scope.RemoveItem = function() {
          $scope.products.splice( this.$index, 1 );
        };

    $scope.products = [
      {
        "name": "Milk",
        "price": 2,
        "currency": "USD",
        "exchangeRate": 1.5,
        "localCurrencyPrice": 0
      },
      {
        "name": "Bread",
        "price": 1,
        "currency": "EUR",
        "exchangeRate": 1,
        "localCurrencyPrice": 0
      },
      {
        "name": "Skittles",
        "price": 3,
        "currency": "GBP",
        "exchangeRate": 2,
        "localCurrencyPrice": 0
      },
      {
        "name": "Nesquik",
        "price": 10,
        "currency": "CHF",
        "exchangeRate": 2.5,
        "localCurrencyPrice": 0
      }
    ]

    });

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time man. However this seems to be working only on initialization of the page. When I change any value for **PRICE** or **EXCHANGERATE** inputs it's not re-calculated again. Also it's not being saved into the scope model and I will need it later on as well.